# SignalR class library for both UWP and WPF

Tags: asp.net-core, uwp, .net-standard, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm interested in writing a class library that can be consumed from both a UWP application and a WPF (desktop) application. This library will incorporate SignalR to allow those two application types to function as servers pushing data. The client will most likely be another UWP application. According to Microsoft in such cases the class library should target .NET Standard. My current understanding is that .NET Core is an implementation of the .NET Standard. Since SignalR has now been included in ASP.NET Core 2.1.0 (which itself is part of .NET Core 2.1) I should be able to accomplish this. However, I only see ".NET Standard 2.0" as the most current version. Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Comment: use .net standard 2.0 for class lib, add here signalR core client nuget package and all SignalR related API code and later reference the .net  standard 2.0 lib from WPF (.net 4.7.2) and UWP (minVersion must be Build 16299) and call methods from your lib.

Comment: You mean I can create a .NET Standard 2.0 class library, arbitrarily add nugget packages to it and it will still be considered a ".NET Standard 2.0" library?

Comment: yes, why not. try it and report if it works