# Fundamentally confused about .NET Standard class library

Tags: .net, .net-standard

This is in response to an answer given in the following thread:

[SignalR class library for both UWP and WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53575699/signalr-class-library-for-both-uwp-and-wpf)

My question is: can I add a nugget package (SignalR and UrhoSharp) to a .NET Standard 2.0 class library project without breaking the cross-framework compatibility of the library? Is this even permitted?

Comment: If you are targeting `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client` NuGet package than Yes, it is compatible with .Net Standard 2.0

Comment: Thank you. How does one determine this i.e. is there somewhere in the documentation where this is formally laid out? I need both client and server functionality in UWP.

Comment: You can check the dependencies of the package in Nuget. Reference [link](https://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net/)